# MVC3 Route Table mistake

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this RegisterRoute function

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
   routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

   routes.Add("JsActionRoute", JsAction.JsActionRouteHandlerInstance.JsActionRoute);
   routes.MapRoute(
      "Default", // Route name
      "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
   );
}
```

Where the JsActionRoute is a route like this.

```
public static readonly Route JsActionRoute = new Route("JsAction",
                                                 new JsAction.JsActionHandler());
```

I want that all links to JsAction/ should be handled by my coustom route.

Now when simply calling `@Html.ActionLink`, Mvc3 creates a link that is related to JsAction, and I can't understand why.

`@Html.ActionLink("About","About") -> JsAction?Action=About&Controller=Index`

Comment: Can you post JsActionHandler code?

Comment: JsActionHanlder simply returns HttpHanlder that manages request (and imports some js files writing them to the response.)

There is something bad with RouteTable priority, but i can't understand why MVC choose JsAction route to generate ActionLinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes are evaluated in the same order as they are registered. You could use the `RouteLink` to explicitly specify a route name:

```
@Html.RouteLink("About", "Default", new { action = "About" })
```

If you inverse the order of definitions then links will generate correctly but your custom route will not be hit when requesting the `JsAction/` url since there is nothing to disambiguate this url from the default route.

You will have to rethink your routes structure so that there are no such conflicts. You could use constraints. Remember that the default route is very eager and if you don't constrain it, it will often take precedence.

One possibility is to define a controller and action for your custom route:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.Add("JsActionRoute", JsAction.JsActionRouteHandlerInstance.JsActionRoute);

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    );

}
```

and then constrain the custom route by specifying a controller and action to be executed:

```
public static readonly Route JsActionRoute = new Route(
    "JsAction", 
    new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "JsAction", controller = "Foo" })
    new JsAction.JsActionHandler()
);
```

Another possibility is to inverse the order of definition of your routes and constrain the default route:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new { controller = "^((?!JsAction).)*$", action = "^((?!JsAction).)*$" }
    );

    routes.Add("JsActionRoute", JsAction.JsActionRouteHandlerInstance.JsActionRoute);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works but i do not like this solution.
Is there any other way to mantain Default route and in same time have all requests to JsAction/ url handled by my handler?

Comment: @Vincenzo, no, since an url like `JsAction/` cannot be disambiguated between your custom route and the default route. The order is important so if you register your route before the default one, it will always be used.

Comment: Is there any other solution, even not using another route handler?

Comment: @Vincenzo, as I said, you will have to rethink your url structure. You might need to modify the default route definition to make it less eager.

Comment: How may i modify default url routing to avoid matching also JsAction url pattern?

Comment: @Vincenzo, inverse the order of route definitions and constrain the default route.

Comment: Thank you, i was just looking to route constraint.
Sorry for bothering you and thank you again for your support.

Comment: @Vincenzo, you could also keep the default route as is and specify a controller and action to be used for the custom route. I have updated my answer.